# Is it legal for a visitor in Dubai to drink alcohol?

Tags: regulations, dubai, alcohol

I’m going to Dubai soon with my sister and two nieces. We are all over 25 and enjoy drinking alcohol socially, with a meal etc. None of us drink to excess or to get drunk. I’ve seen conflicting information about what is and isn’t permitted for foreigners regarding the consumption of alcohol. Are hotels allowed to serve alcohol to their guests? What about restaurants that are not part of a hotel?

Comment: Where have you read that licensed hotels, restaurants and bars are *not* allowed to sell alcohol to tourists?

Comment: The UK gov advice on alcohol consumption in UAE is slightly contradictory - it says hotels etc are allowed to sell it, but also that it’s an offence to drink in public https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/united-arab-emirates/local-laws-and-customs

Comment: Can you please explain the alleged contradiction? As in many western countries, it is prohibited to consume alcohol in public places, but it is of course not prohibited to consume alcohol in the licensed venues with the right to sell alcohol.

Comment: Inside an establishment like a hotel is not usually considered 'in public".

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo I was probably being over-cautious in wondering if hotel bars might be considered public places. It’s not always easy to define, even in one’s own country, eg one city might have a different tolerance level /by-law.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbo Many? Name one besides the USA where it is illegal to visibly open a bottle of alcohol in a park which has not a "Alcohol forbidden" sign and drink it without causing trouble.

Comment: @ThorstenS. I'm having trouble grokking your comment but Canada's rules on public drinking are similar to the US in this regard, at least where I've been.

Comment: @AzorAhai First an apology to all Canadians: I often forget you when "western countries" are meant :(( Sorry, sorry, sorry. Now, apart from Canada, USA and Norway I am not aware of western countries who prohibit drinking alcohol in public. That's still not "many".

Comment: @ThorstenS. You could have found several if you bothered with some trivial research. Even in Germany, your country of residence, there have been city ordinances prohibiting public alcohol consumption, of which most have been lifted during the last 10 years. To mention further western countries, where alcohol consumption in public is generally prohibited or restricted (source Wikipedia): Australia, Austria, Canada, Chile, Czech Republic, Finland, Hungary, Ireland, Netherlands, New Zealand, Norway, Poland, Russia, Slovakia, Spain, Sweden, UK and US.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: it is generally allowed in [Sweden](https://polisen.se/lagar-och-regler/alkohol-offentlig-plats/) (unlike Norway, and I am not interested in any special definition you may have of the word "generally").

Comment: @TomasBy There is absolutely no need for a special definition of 'generally'. As you can read on the page you are linking to, alcohol comsumption in public is restricted in Sweden (I wrote 'generally prohibited or restricted') as it is up to each municipality to decide if consumption is allowed or not. Alcohol consumption is e.g. prohibited in most parks in Stockholm as you can see on this map: http://www.stockholm.se/-/Karta/?lager=163931#lager=163931&centerposition=6580388%2C1626523&zoom=10

Comment: @TorEinarJambo: no it is generally allowed, unless the local municipality has restriced it, _unlike Norway_.

Comment: @TomasBy Please enlighten me: What relevance does it have to this question and where did I write that alcohol consumption in Sweden is not generally allowed?

Comment: @TorEinarJambo: it started with your comment that "in many western countries, it is prohibited to consume alcohol in public places", which I (and others, apparently) took to mean it is generally prohibited. This is, I believe, only true of Norway, US, and maybe some others.

Comment: @TomasBy Alcohol consumption is generally prohibited in several other countries. Assuming that you are from Sweden, just to name a few near-by neighbours: Iceland, Poland and Russia. In Finland, public alcohol consumption is generally prohibited within built-up areas (taajama/tätort). Can you however please answer my question from the previous comment: What relevance does it have to this question? The only one not understanding my comment seem to be you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have never been to Dubai, but all online sources I have found are consistent.

In Dubai, it is prohibited for resident moslems to buy and consume alcohol. Non-moslem residents and visitors above the age of 21 are allowed to buy and consume alcohol with restrictions similar to those in many western countries.

- Alcohol is sold at retail stores. Both the retailer *and the customer* are required to have a license. Such licenses are issued to non-moslem residents, but seem difficult or more or less practically impossible to get as a visitor.
- Alcohol is sold for immediate consumption at licensed bars and restaurants. Visitors are allowed to buy and consume alcohol at these venues.
- Alcohol consumption in public places (and it is obvious that this means 'outside licensed venues') is strictly forbidden and often prosecuted.
- Being under the influence of alcohol is prohibited in public, but there does not seem to be a clearly defined limit. Staggering around obviously drunk is probably not a good idea.
- Driving a vehicle under the influence of alcohol is prohibited.

Comment: I have lived in the UAE and have visited Dubai several times. The answer from @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo describes the situation very well..

Comment: "Visitors are allowed to buy and consume alcohol at these venues."  Since Tomas By's answer directly contradicts this claim, can you provide some evidence?  Also, how does a bar distinguish a visitor from a resident Muslim - do you have to show a foreign passport in order to be served?  (Or are resident Muslims allowed to drink in bars and restaurants?)

Comment: @NateEldredge: there is no contradiction here, between the statements. You can buy and drink but it is technically illegal (as I understand it). I believe the distinction is the dress. Western clothes, ok; arab clothes, no alcohol.

Comment: @NateEldredge The quote from Radha Stirling in Tomas By's answer is contradicted by statements on Detained in Dubai's own home page (section 'Top Drinking in Dubai Recommendations'): https://www.detainedindubai.org/alcohol Summarized, I guess it boils down to 'do not attract attention after drinking alcohol', which Ellie Holman clearly violated when she started arguing with the immigration officer about the validity of her visa.

Comment: I still see no contradiction. It is illegal but tolerated.

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe not.

> It is wholly illegal for any tourist to have any level of alcohol in
>   their blood. It is illegal to consume alcohol at a bar, a hotel and a
>   restaurant and if breathalysed, that person will be jailed.

([said Radha Stirling, CEO of the British human rights NGO *Detained In Dubai*](https://metro.co.uk/2018/08/10/british-mum-jailed-daughter-4-drinking-glass-wine-flight-dubai-7821529/))

Comment: Can you specify the source for your quote?

Comment: Does Stirling have a source for her assertion?

Comment: @Tomas By The news story strikes me as being as much, if not more, about not having the right visa and choosing to argue about it with an official, rather than having drunk supposedly one glass of wine on the flight.

Comment: @Traveller: the bit I quoted was the part I found relevant. I believe she is right. Same with relationships. As long as you don't get noticed you can live as a westerner but if you get into trouble for any reason, then they can make your life very difficult.